# Why EventSubscriberInterface don't work If I want to get a html page

Tags: php, symfony, php-7, symfony5

I add an EventSubscriberInterface In my project to redirect users do not have the right to access and the user not logged in, they do not have access to some pages and urls,my code work but my EventSubscriberInterface does not work If I want to get a page html, even when I add a die() in _construct nothing happened

page html example

/public/modules/story.html

My code

```
public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    {
       $request = $event->getRequest();
       $RequestUri = strtok($request->getRequestUri(), '?');
        if (strpos($RequestUri, '/public/modules') !== false) {
            
            if(empty($_SESSION['_sf2_attributes']['_security.last_username'])){
                //return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_login'));
                $route =$this->urlGenerator->generate('app_login');
                $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($route));
            }else{
            $connection = $this->_em->getConnection();
            $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM eurotest_users eu 
                LEFT JOIN user_range ur On eu.id = ur.user_id 
                LEFT JOIN user_version uv On eu.id = uv.user_id 
                LEFT JOIN eurotest_module em On ur.range_id = em.module_range_id AND uv.version_id = em.module_version_id
                where eu.email ='".$_SESSION['_sf2_attributes']['_security.last_username']."' and em.folder='".$RequestUri."' ");
                $statement->execute();
                $statement->fetchAll();
                $counter = $statement->rowCount();
                if($counter == 0){
                    $route =$this->urlGenerator->generate('app_home');
                    $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($route));
                }
            }   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Symfony processes will be bypassed if you try to access a HTML file directly.

You can try to render this HTML page as a view going through the router like in [this documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#templates-render-from-route)

This will trigger all Symfony's events

Comment: HTML pages are not static

Comment: Do you have the profiler bar on your pages?

Comment: no I don't have

Comment: "HTML pages are not static" - what does that mean? Usually, that's the main difference to any PHP script

Comment: I have many html pages (when I upload a new module can have one or many html pages)

Comment: Even if you have many of them, why are they not static? Do you pipe all HTML files through the PHP modules?